# Why is it difficult to localize shortwave transmissions?

Tags: radio, ham-radio

I have read that it is difficult to localize [shortwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortwave_radio) transmissions, but I don't understand why that is. I know that localizing the bounced transmission is obviously difficult, but when the antenna radiates, it will also radiate locally, so I would guess that local direction finders would be able to easily find the transmitter, just the same way that they would find a VHF transmitter. Is there some reason why that is not true?

Comment: Where did you read about localizing. Please link the reference so the context is fully understood.

Comment: @Andyaka If you don't understand the technical issues involving localization of radio transmissions, then you will not be able to answer the question. I did not ask the question to act as a tutorial on RF localization; I asked to get answers from an expert who understands the subject already.

Comment: Do you actually mean direction finding from two different locations in order to pinpoint the source? That is why I asked because your question is unclear. Also, if you do mean that then why should you limit this to any frequency with a long wavelength? If I have read you correctly then please provide a link for what you have read.